# How to set up Windows Server 2008 r2 Network Load Balancer (NLB) Beginner

Tags: windows, networking, load-balancing

In work we have a set of WCF services which handle thousands upon thousands of transations a day and have decided to use windows NLB and a server farm to handle the Services traffic. We have a virtual IP which will be used for all incoming trafic to the services, 2 servers which will host the WCF services and a 3rd server which hosts the SQL server databases. Our services are stateless.

I have been trawling the internet via Bing and Google looking for some tutorials and videos on how to set up NLB and can not find anything that shows/explains how to set it up from scratch as I am a complete novice.

Can anyone help??